# Modify wording of bulk options

Tags: bulk

I would like to modify the wording in the bulk actions on the posts screen or custom post types. I am trying to do so using the following code, but it's not working. Any idea why?

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'my_custom_bulk_actions' );
function my_custom_bulk_actions( $actions ){
    $actions['trash'] = 'Just testing';

    unset( $actions[ 'edit' ] );
    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no possibility to modify those. Just renaming it (the label in the UI only) via JS is possible.

I'd recommend to not try to modify those strings, as they equal action names and therefore are part of the query strings. You might break things easily. Figuring out what causes things to brake a half year later will just be a pain.

Comment: Would it be ok to add items as done in foxrunsoftware.net/articles/wordpress/add-custom-bulk-action?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Just leave the original names. As I said: Those are the names of actions. If you try that, then A) with js B) at your own risk and C) it's a lot of effort (names are spread over the whole UI like messages, etc.) that will likely break on updates.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, That hook can only be used to remove particular action.

> ```
> // This filter can currently only be used to remove actions.                              
> $this->_actions = apply_filters( 'bulk_actions-' . $this->screen->id, $this->_actions );
> ```
>
> **<sup>Source - [class-wp-list-table.php (Line - 282)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L282)</sup>**

Comment: Here's the track ticket - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16031

Comment: I was hoping someone has come up with a solution to modify the wording, since there is also a solution to add items http://www.foxrunsoftware.net/articles/wordpress/add-custom-bulk-action/